# Realm Objects never deallocated, thus app inevitably crashes because of memory. (Memory Management)

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, realm, automatic-ref-counting

What do you want to achieve?

`UIViewController` `deinit` is called - 0 memory leaks

Expected Results

Realm objects deallocated, thus reference count = 0 and allows `uiviewcontroller` to `deinit`

Actual Results

Realm object never deallocated, standard Out Of Memory crash as no `uiviewcontrollers` are deinitialized.

Steps to Reproduce

Create a few object models, with a major model containing instances of those. Parse data into those optional object models inside the initializer for the major model. This should give you these results.

Code Sample

Here is a standard object I am using (There is more variables but this is an example)

```
class FullData: Object {
    dynamic var venueType: VenueType?
    dynamic var travelerType: TravelerType?

    dynamic var owner: ProfileData?

    let keywords = List<NewKeywords>()
    let cuisines = List<NewCuisines>()
    let images = List<Images>()
}
```

In the `convenience` initialization of this model, I will use a function to create a new `VenueType` Instance , and assign that new instance to the optional variable in the model.

```
  fileprivate func parseVenueType(_ dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        let venues = VenueType()
        dictionary.forEach { (key, val) in
            let keyString = key as! String
            let value = val as! Bool
            switch keyString {
            case "Bar":
                if value == true {
                    venues.bar = true
                }
                break
            case "Restaurant":
                if value == true {
                    venues.restaurant = true
                }
                break
            case "Cafe":
                if value == true {
                    venues.cafe = true
                }
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        venueType = venues
    }
```

Here is the way the `VenueType` and `TravelerType` Classes are setup class

```
class VenueType: Object {
        dynamic var cafe = false
        dynamic var bar = false
        dynamic var restaurant = false
    }
    class TravelerType: Object {
        dynamic var single = false
        dynamic var couple = false
        dynamic var group = false
        dynamic var family = false
    }
```

Using the `Leaks` tool in `Instruments`, I see that there are tons of leaks, all regarding situations almost identical to this. A new instance of an object is created to assign to an object in our model.

Here are some Images detailing these leaks.

I create new instances of a `Objects` all across my app to use as models, but 99.99% of the time I don't persist the models I am creating. I use these as basic models to populate cells, etc. In theory, they should be deallocated once they are done.

Im really unsure what I am doing wrong, as all of my leaks are because of Realm Objects. Its almost as if none of the created models I am using for my data are being deallocated once they leave the view controller.

Am I supposed to do this manually? I have read a few comments on autoreleasepools and also realm.invalidate but am unsure if this would fit my case.

When I create an instance of an Object to assign to a variable in another Object - Do I need to do something special to be sure it deallocates correctly?

Thanks so much for your help.

[image: Full Leak Trace]

[image: Leak line]

[image: retain/release cycles]

[image: Trace for leak]